# What is this type of animation called and how can I replicate it?

Tags: android, android-animation

I saw this animation:

[image].

Do you notice the movement of the FAB and how the playlist hides and unhides? 
Please what's this type of animation called and how can I replicate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collapsing Toolbar](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example_7.html), I hope this tutorial helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy.  Please do you any suggestion as to how I can move the FAB from the toolbar to rest the center-bottom of the screen?

Comment: You're welcome, I think it is a kind of transition effect between 2 fabs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok. I'm thinking, is it possible to get the absolute position of the bottom fab and animate the top fab to that position?

Comment: Actually I don't know please try to google it , you will find an answer hopefully.